# query in mongodb Driver c# for getting Last Array Element in each I am Applying Groupy on Activity Type and I want last array element in each

Tags: c#, mongodb, driver

```
var group = new BsonDocument
{        
    {
        "_id", new BsonDocument {
            {"ActivityType", "$ActivityType"},
        }
    },
    // {
    //    "Result", new BsonDocument("$push", new BsonDocument
    //        {
    //           // { "$slice",-1},
    //            { "SessionRecords", "$SessionRecords" },
    //        }
    //    )
    //},
    {
        "Result", new BsonDocument("$push", new BsonDocument(
            "$slice", new BsonArray
            {
               //new BsonDocument("$slice",new BsonDocument("SessionRecords","$SessionRecords")),
               new BsonArray().Add("$SessionRecords.TemplateId"),
               -1,
            }
            ))
    }
};
```

this is my query and may data is like this
it return all array elements data is like

```
[
    {
        "_id": "62f110c25a1c144e4b4a00ec",  
        "ActivityType":"Working",   
        "SessionRecords": [{
                "TemplateId": "6229dded08714fdbcdf1c969",
                "SecondsCounter": 0,
                "BreathCounter": 0,             
            },
            {
                "TemplateId": "6229dded08714fdbcdf1c969",
                "SecondsCounter": 0,
                "BreathCounter": 0,
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data and of the expected result? Are the lines in the code relevant that have been commented out?

Comment: am added data please check

Comment: and the data which commented is also relevent